# Html to pdf download in laravel 5

Tags: pdf, laravel-5, html2pdf

I am usin barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to convert html page to pdf download.
But I have little problem. here is my code.
I would like to download in "show" as /sale/{id}.
In controller

```
 public function pdf(Request $request,$id)
{
    $sale = Sale::find($id);
    view()->share('sale', $sale);
    if ($request->has('download')) {
        $pdf = PDF::loadview('sale.slip_out_show');
        $pdf->stream();
        return $pdf->download('saleslip_out.pdf');
    }
    return view('sale.slip_out_show');
}
```

in view

```
<a href="{{ route('pdf',['download'=>'pdf']) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

In routes

```
Route::get('pdf', array('as' => 'pdf', 'uses' => 'SaleController@pdf'));
```

but this error found 
**ErrorException in SaleController.php line 105:
Missing argument 2 for App\Http\Controllers\SaleController::pdf()**

Comment: Your Route Callback `pdf` expects an argument `$id` which is not given by the defined Route. You could [pass the sale id to your view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views) from your `show/{id}` callback, then add it to your url like `route('pdf', ['id' => $id, ...` and to your route like `Route::get('pdf/{id}', ...`. This has nothing to do with pdf/html2pdf download or generation.

Comment: ok I already fix this issue but not find yet

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the passing argument on `pdf(Request $request,$id)` method.
You have to pass at least 2 parameter on following href link:

### Pass the download Sales ID

```
<a href="{{ route('pdf',['download'=>'pdf', 'id' => 2]) }}">Download PDF</a>
```

### In route

```
Route::get('pdf/{id}', array('as' => 'pdf', 'uses' => 'SaleController@pdf'));
```

Comment: my update code is 
<a href="{{ action('SaleController@pdf',[$sale->id]) }}">Download PDF</a>
Route::get('pdf/{id}', array('as' => 'pdf', 'uses' => 'SaleController@pdf'));
if I send request process is delay so long loading time.

Comment: I am solve my problem. But download process is so long. There is no large data. I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

This code will download a pdf file with defined content
*

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML($message);
return $pdf->download($file_name);
```

*